# python pygame snake game

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, snake-game

I used numpy for the O(n) parts, but I didn't add any ability to change grid size because I still wonder if there's a way to make it better than O(n).

`main.py`:

```py
import pygame
import numpy as np
from random import randrange
from clickablebox import ClickableBox

# values of grid spaces
EMPTY = 0
BUG = 1
SNAKE_UP = 2
SNAKE_RIGHT = 3
SNAKE_DOWN = 4
SNAKE_LEFT = 5

GRID_COLORS = (
    (200, 200, 200),
    (65, 163, 23),
    (255, 243, 128),
    (255, 243, 128),
    (255, 243, 128),
    (255, 243, 128)
)

GRID_Y_OFFSET = 20
GRID_X_OFFSET = 20
GRID_HEIGHT = 16
GRID_WIDTH = 16
GRID_SPACE_SIZE = 35

TICKS_BETWEEN_MOVEMENT = 15 # 1 tick is 16 milliseconds

class Game:
    def __init__(self):
        # numpy used instead of list for self.available_bug_spaces because it needs to find and to remove values, which is O(n)
        self.available_bug_spaces = None
        
        self.grid = []
        self.tail = (0, 0)
        self.head = (0, 0)
    
    
    def setup_game(self):
        # setting up lists
        self.available_bug_spaces = np.arange(GRID_HEIGHT * GRID_WIDTH, dtype=np.uint64)
        self.grid.clear()
        for _ in range(GRID_HEIGHT):
            self.grid.append([EMPTY] * GRID_WIDTH)
        
        # setting initial snake spaces
        mid_y = GRID_HEIGHT // 2
        mid_x = GRID_WIDTH // 2
        for x in range(mid_x, mid_x + 5):
            self.grid[mid_y][x] = SNAKE_LEFT
        
        self.available_bug_spaces = np.delete(self.available_bug_spaces, range((mid_y * GRID_WIDTH) + mid_x, (mid_y * GRID_WIDTH) + mid_x + 5))
        self.place_bug()
        
        self.head = (mid_y, mid_x)
        self.tail = (mid_y, x)
    
    
    def place_bug(self):
        # I can't figure out how to make this part better than O(n)
        if len(self.available_bug_spaces) == 0:
            return (-1, -1) # player won
        available_bug_spaces_index = randrange(len(self.available_bug_spaces))
        available_bug_spaces_value = self.available_bug_spaces[available_bug_spaces_index]
        bug_y, bug_x = int(available_bug_spaces_value) // GRID_WIDTH, int(available_bug_spaces_value) % GRID_WIDTH
        self.available_bug_spaces = np.delete(self.available_bug_spaces, (available_bug_spaces_index,))
        self.grid[bug_y][bug_x] = BUG
        return (bug_y, bug_x)
    
    
    def get_next_coord(self, coord, direction):
        vertical_change, horizontal_change = ((-1, 0), (0, 1), (1, 0), (0, -1))[direction - SNAKE_UP]
        return (coord[0] + vertical_change, coord[1] + horizontal_change)
    
    
    def move_forward_no_bug(self, next_head_coord, head_direction):
        old_tail_coord = self.tail
        tail_direction = self.grid[self.tail[0]][self.tail[1]]
        next_tail_coord = self.get_next_coord(self.tail, tail_direction)
        self.grid[self.tail[0]][self.tail[1]] = 0
        self.grid[self.head[0]][self.head[1]] = head_direction
        self.grid[next_head_coord[0]][next_head_coord[1]] = head_direction
        
        # switch out new head position with old tail position
        # I can't figure out how to make this part better than O(n)
        
        self.available_bug_spaces[np.where(self.available_bug_spaces == (next_head_coord[0] * GRID_WIDTH) + next_head_coord[1])[0][0]] = (self.tail[0] * GRID_WIDTH) + self.tail[1]
        
        self.head = next_head_coord
        self.tail = next_tail_coord
        
        return self.head, old_tail_coord
    
    
    def move_forward_eat_bug(self, next_head_coord, head_direction):
        self.grid[self.head[0]][self.head[1]] = head_direction
        self.grid[next_head_coord[0]][next_head_coord[1]] = head_direction
        bug_coord = self.place_bug()
        
        self.head = next_head_coord
        
        return self.head, bug_coord


class GUI:
    
    def __init__(self):
        self.win = pygame.display.set_mode((1200, 700))
        self.font = pygame.font.Font(pygame.font.get_default_font(), 30)
        self.start_button = ClickableBox(self.win, self.font, "start", (1105, 515), (1090, 480), (100, 100))
        self.quit_button = ClickableBox(self.win, self.font, "quit", (1110, 625), (1090, 590), (100, 100))
        self.start_button.draw()
        self.quit_button.draw()
        self.menu_drawn = True
    
    
    def toggle_menu_screen(self):
        self.set_message("")
        if self.menu_drawn: # this means the menu is currently drawn
            self.start_button.undraw()
            self.menu_drawn = False
        else:
            pygame.draw.rect(self.win, (0, 0, 0), (GRID_X_OFFSET, GRID_Y_OFFSET, GRID_SPACE_SIZE * GRID_WIDTH, GRID_SPACE_SIZE * GRID_HEIGHT)) # undrawing grid
            self.start_button.draw()
            self.menu_drawn = True
    
    
    def set_message(self, message):
        pygame.draw.rect(self.win, (0, 0, 0), (150, 600, 940, 100))
        text_surface = self.font.render(message, True, (50, 50, 50))
        self.win.blit(text_surface, (150, 650))
    
    
    def draw_grid(self, grid):
        for y in range(GRID_HEIGHT):
            for x in range(GRID_WIDTH):
                pygame.draw.rect(self.win, GRID_COLORS[grid[y][x]], (GRID_X_OFFSET + (x * GRID_SPACE_SIZE), GRID_Y_OFFSET + (y * GRID_SPACE_SIZE), GRID_SPACE_SIZE, GRID_SPACE_SIZE))
    
    
    def draw_coords(self, grid, coords):
        for coord in coords:
            pygame.draw.rect(self.win, GRID_COLORS[grid[coord[0]][coord[1]]], (GRID_X_OFFSET + (coord[1] * GRID_SPACE_SIZE), GRID_Y_OFFSET + (coord[0] * GRID_SPACE_SIZE), GRID_SPACE_SIZE, GRID_SPACE_SIZE))


def wait_for_unpause(gui):
    while True:
        pygame.time.wait(16)
        pygame.display.update()
        
        events = pygame.event.get()
        for event in events:
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                return False, False
            elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP and event.button == 1 and gui.quit_button.clicked(pygame.mouse.get_pos()):
                return False, True
            elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_p:
                return True, True


def wait_for_input(gui):
    while True:
        pygame.time.wait(16)
        pygame.display.update()
        
        events = pygame.event.get()
        for event in events:
            if (
                (event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP and event.button == 1 and gui.quit_button.clicked(pygame.mouse.get_pos()))
                or event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN
                or event.type == pygame.QUIT
                ):
                return event.type != pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP, pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP != pygame.QUIT


def play_game(game, gui):
    gui.set_message("")
    ticks_since_last_movement = 0
    direction = None
    current_head_direction = game.grid[game.head[0]][game.head[1]]
    
    while True:
        pygame.time.wait(16)
        pygame.display.update()
        ticks_since_last_movement += 1
        
        events = pygame.event.get()
        for event in events:
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                return False, False
            elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP and event.button == 1 and gui.quit_button.clicked(pygame.mouse.get_pos()):
                return False, True
            elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if (event.key == pygame.K_UP or event.key == pygame.K_w) and current_head_direction != SNAKE_DOWN:
                    direction = SNAKE_UP
                elif (event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT or event.key == pygame.K_d) and current_head_direction != SNAKE_LEFT:
                    direction = SNAKE_RIGHT
                elif (event.key == pygame.K_DOWN or event.key == pygame.K_s) and current_head_direction != SNAKE_UP:
                    direction = SNAKE_DOWN
                elif (event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == pygame.K_a) and current_head_direction != SNAKE_RIGHT:
                    direction = SNAKE_LEFT
                elif event.key == pygame.K_p:
                    ticks_since_last_movement = 0
                    gui.set_message("paused")
                    keep_playing, keep_running = wait_for_unpause(gui)
                    if not keep_playing or not keep_running:
                        return keep_playing, keep_running
                    gui.set_message("")
        if direction is not None or ticks_since_last_movement == TICKS_BETWEEN_MOVEMENT:
            if direction is None:
                direction = game.grid[game.head[0]][game.head[1]]
            ticks_since_last_movement = 0
            next_head_y, next_head_x = game.get_next_coord(game.head, direction)
            if not 0 <= next_head_y < GRID_HEIGHT or not 0 <= next_head_x < GRID_WIDTH or SNAKE_UP <= game.grid[next_head_y][next_head_x] <= SNAKE_LEFT:
                gui.set_message("you lose, press any key to reset")
                return wait_for_input(gui)
            if game.grid[next_head_y][next_head_x] == EMPTY:
                head, old_tail = game.move_forward_no_bug((next_head_y, next_head_x), direction)
                gui.draw_coords(game.grid, (head, old_tail))
            else:
                head, bug_coord = game.move_forward_eat_bug((next_head_y, next_head_x), direction)
                if bug_coord == (-1, -1):
                    gui.set_message("you win, press any key to reset")
                    return wait_for_input(gui)
                gui.draw_coords(game.grid, (head, bug_coord))
            current_head_direction = game.grid[game.head[0]][game.head[1]]
            direction = None


def main():
    pygame.init()
    pygame.display.set_caption("snake game")
    game = Game()
    gui = GUI()
    
    keep_running = True
    while keep_running:
        pygame.time.wait(16)
        pygame.display.update()
        
        events = pygame.event.get()
        for event in events:
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                keep_running = False
            elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP and event.button == 1:
                if gui.quit_button.clicked(pygame.mouse.get_pos()):
                    keep_running = False
                elif gui.start_button.clicked(pygame.mouse.get_pos()):
                    gui.toggle_menu_screen()
                    keep_playing = True
                    while keep_playing:
                        game.setup_game()
                        gui.set_message("press any key to start")
                        gui.draw_grid(game.grid)
                        pygame.display.update()
                        keep_playing, keep_running = wait_for_input(gui)
                        if keep_playing:
                            keep_playing, keep_running = play_game(game, gui)
                    gui.toggle_menu_screen()
    
    pygame.quit()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

`clickablebox.py` (`TextEntryBox` not used in this):

```py
import pygame

class ClickableBox:
    
    def __init__(self, win, font, text, text_location, box_location, dimensions):
        self.font = font
        self.text = text
        self.text_location = text_location
        self.box_location = box_location
        self.dimensions = dimensions
        
        self.win = win
        self.box = None
    
    
    def draw(self, color=(150, 150, 150)):
        self.box = pygame.draw.rect(self.win, color, (*self.box_location, *self.dimensions))
        text_surface = self.font.render(self.text, True, (50, 50, 50))
        self.win.blit(text_surface, self.text_location)
    
    
    def undraw(self):
        pygame.draw.rect(self.win, (0, 0, 0), (*self.box_location, *self.dimensions))
        self.box = None
    
    
    def clicked(self, coords):
        return self.box is not None and self.box.collidepoint(coords)


class TextEntryBox(ClickableBox):
    
    def __init__(self, win, font, text, text_location, box_location, dimensions, typing_location, max_text):
        super().__init__(win, font, text, text_location, box_location, dimensions)
        self.typing_location = typing_location
        self.max_text = max_text
        self.box_text = ""
    
    
    def draw(self, text, color=(150, 150, 150)):
        super().draw(color)
        text = str(text)[:self.max_text]
        typing_surface = self.font.render(text, True, (70, 70, 70))
        self.win.blit(typing_surface, self.typing_location)
        self.box_text = text
    
    
    def undraw(self):
        upper_left_undraw_box = (self.box_location[0], self.text_location[1])
        undraw_box_dimensions = (self.dimensions[0], self.dimensions[1] + (self.box_location[1] - self.text_location[1]))
        pygame.draw.rect(self.win, (0, 0, 0), (*upper_left_undraw_box, *undraw_box_dimensions))
        self.box = None
```

Comment: I had one idea for O(1) but placement where: you have one list containing empty spaces, one list containing occupied spaces, and one list containing where each coordinate in referenced in either list. Then when bugs are placed and the snake is moving, you switch coordinates around between both lists. But I'm not sure if that idea will actually work because I haven't tested it or thought about it very hard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that, directly after construction, `Game` is unusable and requires a call to `setup_game`. You also have one `Game` instance that's reused via multiple `setup_game` calls that each trample the contents of the class. To fix these issues, and to deter harmful state mutation, on the inside of your `main()` loop just construct a game instance each time. Merge your setup code into the constructor.

Add PEP484 type hints to your function signatures.

> I can't figure out how to make this part better than O(n)

The O(n) comes from your `np.delete`. I'm not convinced that there's a very good role for Numpy in this application, especially for `available_bug_spaces`.

The first instinct is to use a built-in `set` to represent your `available_bug_spaces`; this will have amortised O(1) membership test, insertion and deletion. But this comes with an asterisk: if you try to `random.sample()` on the set, this is now deprecated; if you try it now you will see something like

```
DeprecationWarning: Sampling from a set deprecated
since Python 3.9 and will be removed in a subsequent version.
```

Read e.g. [random.choice from set?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15837729/random-choice-from-set-python) and its links.

Since your grid is only 16x16, efficiency is not that big a deal, so it's almost certainly not worth implementing an exotic data structure for this purpose. You could do worse than to

- Use a built-in set of available coordinates
- When moving normally, all operations will be O(1) amortised
- When placing a new bug, cast to a tuple to `random.choice()` on it; this will be O(n) but is relatively rare so it makes sense to eat the cost here